# Junção de datas Tableau

Tags: dataset

Tenho dois campos de datas de fontes diferentes no tableau, porém as datas são distintas, uma não é relacionada a outra.Como posso relacionar as duas para criar um filtro unico de data.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Preciso criar um filtro unico com os campos de datas de fontes diferentes. Porém não consigo fazer por relacionamento, pois uma data não é igual a outra.